# Page not found should works with rewrite rule htacces 

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

I  want to rewrite my url from php extention to html.and if that file was not 
found then it should redirect to some custome page(404.php).

I have written rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ front/index.php?query=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)\.(html) ?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
ErrorDocument    404    /expertLocal/?page=404
```

using this i am facing problem like this. http://somedomain.com/expertLocal/contact.html

it will work file coz i have contact.php page . if i will write    somedomain.com/expertLocal/contactxyz.php then it redirect to 404.php page but if i will write http://somedomain.com/expertLocal/contactxyz.html in address bar then it will give warnings instead of 404.php page.

This is because  i ahve used my own framework and in this structure file is first redirect to controller index file and then included requested file there.

```
include(FRONT_CONTROLLER_PATH . $page . '.php');   like this.
```

Can you please help me out?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Here you have contact controller which is handling contact.html file.. Right?? Post your warning message. Is it MVC error?

Answer (score 0):

I am  not sure about your framework, but check below code if it helps.

```
$filename = FRONT_CONTROLLER_PATH . $page . '.php';
if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
       include($filename); 
}
else
{
       // include 404 page here
}
```

Comment: Do you already have 404 page on your project? Directly run http://somedomain.com/expertLocal/404.html in browser if it is working?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ front/index.php?query=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)\.(html) ?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
ErrorDocument    404    /expertLocal/?page=404   

whatever i pass in page name its first go to front/index.php page coz in project we have that file so i think using htaccess rule i cant achieve so its better to use php code for file exist in controller file.